# Sieve of Eratosthenes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I found this method kinda tough to get for a beginner like me, but I tried to do my best, and here's what I came up with.

Is this good code regarding performance? Is there anything wrong with it?

```
var notPrime = [] ;
var prime = [] ;

var n = prompt("Enter n: ");

for(var i = 2 ; i < n ; i++ ){

    if(notPrime.indexOf(i) != -1){              
        continue;
    }   

    for(var j = i ; i <= j ; j++){
        if((i * j) < n){
            notPrime.push(i*j);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    prime.push(i);
}

for(var f in prime){
    console.log(prime[f]);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Lets say that there is room for improvement. ;)

---

The `prompt` method returns a string, but you want a number, so you should parse the string:

```
var n = parseInt(prompt("Enter n: "), 10);
```

---

Using `indexOf` on an array is slow. Instead of putting all the non-primes in a bucket and rummaging through it, you should use an array containing boolean values where the index is the number and the values tells you if it's a prime or not.

Accessing an array by index is an O(1) operation, while searching for a value in an array is an O(n) operaton. As n grows, this code will get slower and slower the longer you let it run.

As you are pushing a lot of duplicate non-primes in the array, an array of boolean values will actually use about 70% less memory eventhough the primes also takes up space in it.

---

This loop is pretty pointless:

```
for(var j = i ; i <= j ; j++){
```

The condition will never be false. You should instead use the `i * j < n` condition to break out of the loop:

```
for(var j = i; i * j < n; j++){
  notPrime[i * j] = true;
}
```

---

#### Edit:

You are still using the array as a kind of collection. You should set all values to true at start, and then set all non-primes to false. This code (based on the algorithm [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)) is about five times faster:

```
var n = parseInt(prompt("Enter n: "), 10);
var i, j;
var prime = new Array(n);
for (i = 2; i < n ; i++) prime[i] = true;

for (i = 2; i * i < n ; i++) {
  if (prime[i]) {
    for (j = 0; i * i + i * j < n ; j++) {
      prime[i * i + i * j] = false;
    }
  }
}

var cnt = 0;
for (i = 2 ; i < n ; i++) {
  if (prime[i]){
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. The array of boolean values note really helped. It accelerate the whole process, eg: finding primes in from 0 to 20000 with the old code hangs the browser. But with the boolean values it works great. Thanks

Comment: @Rafael: You are still using the array as a kind of collection. You should use the value in the array instead of checking for the existance of items. See the code added above.

Comment: mmmm, i tried the code you wrote. I'm afraid i don't notice a big difference, it's actually the same as the one i edited it.

Comment: @Rafael: I see a big difference: http://jsperf.com/sieve-versions

Comment: mmmm, maybe it's just my computer. I don't really know, i'll try it again though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I made some improvements and speed up this code.

---

```
var prime = new Array(n);
for (i = 2; i < n ; i++) prime[i] = true;
```

replaced by 2x faster

```
var prime = [];
for (i = 0; i <= n ; i++) prime.push(true);
```

---

```
for (i = 2; i * i < n ; i++) {
```

`i * i` is calculated every time, replaced by

```
for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n)|0; i++) {
```

Math.sqrt(n)|0 reduces unneeded calculations

---

```
for (j = 0; i * i + i * j <= n ; j++) {
  prime[i * i + i * j] = false;
```

Here are so many calculations iterated every time. I reduced them to:

```
for (var j = i*i; j <= n; j += i) {
  prime[j] = false;
```

---

```
function sieve5(n) {
  var i,j;
  // true-table
  var prime = [];
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) prime.push(true); // mark 'numbers' 0..n as 'true'

  // mark for swipe
  for (i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n)|0; i++) {
    if (prime[i]) {
      for (j = i*i; j <= n ;j += i) {
        prime[j] = false; // eliminate all none prime numbers and mark them as 'false'
      }
    }
  }

  // extract primes
  var primes = [];
  for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) { // 'zero' and 'one' is not prime
    if (prime[i]) primes.push(i) // get all primes from 2..n
  }

  return primes;
}
console.time("sieve5");
primes = sieve5(1000000);// 62ms on my PC
console.timeEnd("sieve5");
console.log('length=',primes.length);

primes = sieve5(100);
console.log(primes);
// [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
console.log(sieve5(11));//[2,3,5,7,11]
```

Comment: I do not totally get why downvote. The code improvements are good, left alone without pushes gives more than twice speedup. And the killer comes from [push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614126/why-is-array-push-sometimes-faster-than-arrayn-value). Funny thing - alone push test in Firefox is faster than loop (fill also), on Chrome oposite, but *sieve5* consistently outperforms other sieves. +1 from me.

Comment: @Evil What was faster for you, `prime[i] = true;` or `prime.push(true);` ? For me `prime.push(true);`

Comment: `prime.push(true)` on Firefox, `prime[i] = true` on Chrome, I have tried with `prime.fill(true)` but this is a bit of lottery. Also I tried with things like to store `Math.sqrt(n) | 0` to a variable, but it gives neglible saving.

Comment: `var max = Math.sqrt(n) | 0` is a good idea, I do not remember I tested it, but I believe I did.